# Why original numpy array gets updated after updating of its copy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been puzzled with unexpected Python behavior: when I make a copy of my original **numpy array** and **replace** some of its elements with a **different** value, the **corresponding** elements of my original array gets updated, too. Here's a simple test:

```
>>import numpy as np
>>x = np.array([0,0,2,2])
>>x_adj = x
>>x_adj[x_adj <= 0] = 1
>>print x
>>print x_adj
  [1 1 2 2]
  [1 1 2 2]
```

I wonder, why the original array gets updated, too, and how to keep it intact so changes will be made to the copy only. Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: This is standard behavior in python. The copy is a reference to the original. Use `deepcopy` in standard python or `<variable>.copy` in numpy.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! So is the referencing to the original when using '=' common across all python libraries (core, numpy, pandas) and for all objects (lists, arrays, data frames)?

Comment: I don't want to overstate, but everything that's based on an object and everything that I'm aware off. It should be your default assumption.

Comment: Thanks, good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment **is not a copy of an object** in numpy. You are just coping the reference to an object, to make a copy of actual array use

```
x_adj = x.copy()
```

you can easily check it through `id` function

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([0])
>>> print id(x)
140686120123168
>>> x_adj = x
>>> print id(x_adj)
140686120123168
>>> print id(x.copy())
140685864181632
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!